# Extracting long date in Python Pandas format

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe which contains some a date column that is need of cleaning. Im trying with re or contains, so far I have not succeed.

```
     Date 
1 January 2004 : ygagy
3 December 2001 , this job
...04 February 2000 , xyz
```

Ideally I would need to look like this:

```
    Date
01 January 2004 
03 December 2001 
04 February 2000
```

Comment: full string in a line is one column ?

Answer (score 0):

This might help. Using **dateutil** module

```
import dateutil.parser as dparser
df["Date"] = [dparser.parse(i,fuzzy=True).strftime('%d %B, %Y') for i in df['Date']]
```

**Output**:

```
0     01 January, 2004
1    03 December, 2001
2    04 February, 2000
Name: Date, dtype: object
```

**And Using Regex:**

```
df["Date"] = df.Date.apply(lambda x: re.findall('\d{1,2} \w{3,9} \d{4}', x)[0])    
print df["Date"]
```

**Output:**

```
0      1 January 2004
1     3 December 2001
2    04 February 2000
3     01 Januari 2017
Name: Date, dtype: object
```

Comment: Hi Rakesh , I got the following error : (ValueError: Unknown string format) .. My old code that did not work was   df['date'] = df.date.apply(lambda x: re.findall('\d{1,2} \w{ 4,8} \d{1,4}', x)[0])

Comment: Hi Rakesh , tks for promptly reply.. line 1182, in parse
    return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/iandeoliveira/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dateutil/parser.py", line 559, in parse
    raise ValueError("Unknown string format")
ValueError: Unknown string format

Comment: Looks like the date string is invalid in your df. It is not like you have in your example

Comment: Hi Rakesh some entries can be quite long .. for example : 10  Applications are due in the Rio Tinto office by  no later than $% # 01 Januari 2017.